# Express / Heroku not redirecting to https

Tags: express, heroku, https

What is the up to date solution for redirecting to make connection secure for my heroku website that is running on express server?

I tried everything.

- Solution number one: https://github.com/developer239/workbox-webpack-react/commit/7e0b5073d4fb7d59408ad2269cc946ef21292bdf
- Solution number two: https://github.com/developer239/workbox-webpack-react/commit/f3ed48bb5309597d5020560d5f9e964823e01883
- Solution number three: https://github.com/developer239/workbox-webpack-react/commit/8f62c8e39c747e88b28498e1bc44204340479dc5
- Solution number four: https://github.com/developer239/workbox-webpack-react/commit/9e12c2b25a687585d690d650822d7f912d51ddbe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solutions above should work fine. There was a problem with Heroku. It uses some kind of proxy. This code snippet should fix it:

```
// require https
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (req.hostname !== 'localhost' && req.get('X-Forwarded-Proto') !== 'https') {
    return res.redirect(`https://${req.hostname}${req.url}`)
  }
  return next()
})
```